# How can I make the Mouse Move Relative to its last position

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouse, pyautogui, mousemove

I have class labels and (x,y) coordinates, I want to control basic mouse operations based on that. So far I can perform the operations like move mouse, single click (left mouse button), double click, and right click.
The issue I am facing is that the cursor moves to the absolute position, But I want to make it move from the last position.
here is the function:

```
import mouse as m
def OperateMouse(mX,mY,sW,sH,classLabl):

    if classLabl == "Close":
        print("Close Sign Detected... Exiting")
        return False
    if classLabl == "Move":
        #mX = sW + ((mX - (sW/2))*sW/(sW/2)-(sH/2))
        m.move(mX,mY)
    elif classLabl == "SC":
        m.click(button='left')
    elif classLabl == "T_DC":
        m.double_click(button='left')
    elif classLabl == "RC":
        m.right_click()
```

Here, mX and mY are the coordinates that I am getting from an output window which is half the size of screen, sW and sH are screen width and height.
I also tried pyautogui before using mouse.

here is the modification I tried:

```
lX, lY = pyautogui.position()
print("Last Pos:" , lX, lY)
print("Curnt Pos:" , mX, mY)
print("Diff = " , mX-lX, mY-lY)
nX, nY = mX-lX, mY-lY
mX, mY = mX+nX, mY+nY
#m.move(mX-lX, mY-lY)
try:
    pyautogui.move(mX,mY)
    if pyautogui.failSafeCheck():
        raise pyautogui.FailSafeException()
except:
    print("FailSafe Exception")
```

does not work, FailSafe exception is raised as it jumps to the bottom right corner

Comment: Extend your program so that it keeps track of the mouse position. For example, after the first `m.move(mX,mY)` the code can store the values of `mX` and `mY`. Then to do a relative move, calculate the new position by adding the displacement to the previous one.

Comment: @BoarGules I tried doing that but it just jumps to the corner as it is changing continuously in real-time

Comment: Don't use an answer to modify your question. Edit the original question instead. See the links Share Edit Follow Close Flag? There. It wasn't clear from your original question what you were trying to do. You seemed to want to move the mouse relative to its previous position. But it appears that what you are really trying to do is to rescale the coordinates. Is that correct?

Comment: @BoarGules I am sorry, I was in a hurry and instead of editing, I answered. But what I am trying to do is to make the mouse follow a dot which is moving in a separate output window in real-time. The window is in upper left corner of the screen and is half the size of screen in terms of width and height. The issue I am facing is that if the dot is disappeared let's from position (10,15) and appears at (120,130), I want the mouse to move from previous position i.e., (10,15) but it just jumps to (120,130). I hope I have explained it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

PyAutoGUI supports both an absolute move and a relative move.

- `pyautogui.moveRel(xOffset, yOffset)` moves the mouse relative to it's current position.
- `pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)` moves to the specified screen coordinates.

If you look in the [PyAutoGUI source code](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/a62027c63fdeccfaaa0e8eda9e999cdea28a1a02/pyautogui/__init__.py#L1307) you can see that `move()` is just an alias of `moveRel()` that was added in v1.0

If you're wanting to convert coordinates from windowspace to screen space you'll want to first calculate the location of the window in screen space and use that as an offset when calculating screen space coordinates.